# importing module behaves differently in Jupyter notebook and Interpreter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

say, we have a module **my_module.py**

```
def test():
    pass

print("hello world")
```

And another file **test.py** with one line of code

```
import my_module
```

- when we run *python3 test.py*, Python will print out "hello world"
- in Python interactive environment, if we type "import my_module
  ", Python will also print out "hello world"

However, in a cell in the **Jupyter notebook**, if I wrote 'import my_module' and run the cell, it does not print out the "hello world" message...(the module is successfully imported though as I can call the my_module.test() function)

is it an intended behaviour for Jupyter notebook? I am curious about why such a difference?

Comment: Jupyter notebook may run in different directory then you regular python (like anaconda). make sure your module is in same directory.

Comment: @Roim I could call my_module.test(), so the module was successfully imported. Just curious about why the print function was not executed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that what I thought...but somehow the print function was executed when I imported the module...did I miss anything here?

Comment: @TimChen to be clear, the print **should** run on import. Why it isn't happening in Jupyter I don't know, but notebooks Dona lot of stuff with standard input/output, maybe it silences it somewhere. I'm not at my computer so I'm not sure I can reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is that you neglected to import all of **test.py** when you imported `my_module`. (I presume that your **__init__.py** is either empty or just imports the function `test()`). If you do `from my_module import test` or `from my_module.test import *`, everything *should* work as expected:

[image: jupyter_img]

Note that I modified `test()` in **test.py** to be:

```
def test():
    print("running test() in test.py")
```

---

**EDIT**: I apologize for the confusion, I accidentally named my files differently than you. I originally didn't name any files to be my_module.py, but instead had test.py be equivalent to your my_module.py. I've now corrected this.

My original folder structure was as follows:

```
Untitled.ipynb
my_module
├── test.py
└── __init__.py
```

Here is the new folder structure:

```
my_module
├── Untitled.ipynb
├── my_module.py
├── test.py
└── __init__.py
```

And the files are

**my_module.py**

```
def test():
    print("running test() in my_module.py")

print("goodbye world")
```

**test.py**

```
import my_module

my_module.test()
```

And if you `import test` in **Untitled.ipynb**, you get the following:
[image: jupyter_img2]

If you shut down and reconnect the kernel, you can then `import my_module` to get the following:
[image: jupyter_img3]

This works as expected.

If you want this to work outside of your **my_module** folder, I suggest you rename **my_module.py**. This is because, inside the folder, running **test.py** will import the file **my_module.py**, but outside the folder, **test.py** will import the entire folder **my_module**, which coincidentally contains **test.py**. To see this in action, add `print(help(my_module))` to **test.py** just after `import my_module`. You'll find that this prints very different things depending on where you call **test.py** from.

To improve clarity a bit, let's add another file called **test2.py** to the folder, and rename the function in **my_module.py** from `test()` to `some_func()`.

Importing **test.py** in a notebook from inside the folder yields:
[image: jupyter_img4]

Importing **test.py** from outside the folder yields:
[image: jupyter_img5]

As you can see, it's a bit confused as to what you want **test.py** to actually import.

If you wanted the second option to print random stuff, you'd probably have to put it in your **__init__.py** file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my question is really about the print function in the global scope of the my_modudle.py file. When importing the module in the Jupyter notebook, that print function was not called for some reason...

Comment: @TimChen My apologies for the confusion. I've now updated my answer accordingly

Comment: ahh, now I got it. Your comment on the "reconnecting kernel" is the key! I overlooked the fact that even if I updated the my_module.py, the Jupyter notebook will still think it has imported the module already!

Comment: For future projects, you can also use the cell magics `%load_ext autoreload` followed by `%autoreload 2` before your import statements in jupyter. This will let you modify functions in your modules without having to kill the kernel every time, although I don't think it will print new stuff on import without shutting down and reconnecting first